# Copy properties but not function properties, using spread operator or similar

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-next

Is there a way in JS to copy all non-function properties using the spread operator or the like? this won't do it obviously (since it will copy function references):

```
  getSerializableData(): Partial<this> {
    return {
      ...this,
      subscribers: undefined,
      subscribersByEvent: undefined,
      
    }
  }
```

in pseudo-code it would be like:

```
  getSerializableData(): Partial<this> {
    return {
      ...Object.serializableFields(this),   // <<< here
      subscribers: undefined,
      subscribersByEvent: undefined,
    }
  }
```

so the spread operator would only act on non-functions properties, etc.
Is this possible?

Comment: No, there's no builtin. You need to filter them yourself. What do you need this for? Why do you have functions that you don't want on the object in the first place?

Comment: You could write your own function which acts like this, sort of a filtered version of `Object.assign()`.  Could you provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE? That would make it possible to test any prospective solution (like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/mM8RkN)), and you'd have a better chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: @Bergi going to send this obj over wire so don't need to copy functions, might log stuff intermediately and don't want to see functions there either

Comment: @AlexanderMills How are you going to "*send this obj over wire*"? Usually the functions are dropped when serialising the object onto the wire representation, not in a separate step.

Comment: In this case I am logging some stuff and just don't really need to see the functions in between

Comment: What logger are you using? You may want to customise the logging of your objects, or make your methods non-enumerable and/or put them on the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the entries by value type, and then use a reduce function to zip the object back up.

```js
const filteredObject = Object.entries(this)
  .filter(it => typeof(it[1] !== 'function'))
  .reduce( (acc,item) => { acc[item[0]]=item[1]; return acc }, {} )
```

As Bergi suggested, you can zip up your object using `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
const entries = Object.entries(this)
  .filter(it => typeof(it[1] !== 'function'))

const filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(entries)
```

Comment: Use `Object.fromEntries` not a custom `reduce`

Comment: That's sugar :), but i will add it to solution @Bergi